# What does the sixth line in the output of the Bitcoin Core GUI RPC command "gettxoutsetinfo" mean?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

An example of the output of this RPC command is as follows.

```
 1  "height":n,     (numeric) The current block height (index)
 2  "bestblock": "hex",   (string) The hash of the block at the tip of the chain
 3  "transactions": n,      (numeric) The number of transactions with unspent outputs
 4  "txouts": n,            (numeric) The number of unspent transaction outputs
 5  "bogosize": n,          (numeric) A meaningless metric for UTXO set size
 6  "hash_serialized_2": "hash", (string) The serialized hash
 7  "disk_size": n,         (numeric) The estimated size of the chainstate on disk
 8  "total_amount": x.xxx          (numeric) The total amount
}
```

What's the meaning of the sixth line "hash_serialized_2"? Whose hash is this referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a hash of the entire serialized UTXO set. You can use to verify that a node's UTXO set is uncorrupted (by comparing it with another node that runs the same command, at the same height).

The `_2` prefix is to indicate the hashing algorithm that is used. Earlier versions used a different algorithm that became very hard to support efficiently. It's just there so people don't expect the hashes to be comparable between old and new nodes.